# Drupal6: No blog node can be edited

Tags: drupal-6

Going to `http://www.example.com/node/NID/edit`, where NID is any valid nid referring to a node of the `story` content type, results in the following error:

`warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'blog_node_form' was given in /home/site/public_html/site2/includes/form.inc on line 367.`

I'm using the standard Drupal blog module.

Editing is impossible. What could this be?

Curiously, the afflicted nodes are listed as type `blog` in the database, but `node_types` does not contain any entry about `blog`.

A bunch of modules were just disabled, then re-enabled. Perhaps that caused a problem?

Comment: You should ask this at superuser.com

Comment: Dubious. What if it's an issue with a custom module I wrote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: Blog module was not enabled. Re-enabling it solves the problem.